# How to select pandas groupby indices by a regex match and return a groupby subset

Tags: pandas, group-by

I expect there is an answer somewhere but I've looked and not found one that specifically shows me where I'm going wrong.
I saved some previous (and not easily reproduced) data in a pickle storing a 'groupby' pandas object.

```
mygrpobj = pickle.load(srcfile)
```

So there it is,  only a groupby object is available.
Now I want to reduce this groupby object based on a regex match against the indices.

It should be easy,  but, both

```
mydf = mygrpobj.filter(lambda x:pd.notna(re.match('string', x.name)))
mydf = mygrpobj.filter(any)
```

lose the grouping index that I want to filter by, so now I can't re-groupby using the original grouping name.

I understand that 'filter' is not really a tool for filtering the group but for the dataframes within each group, but I had hoped that filter(any) would get back my original dataframe.

So I know that I can 'hack' this by using mygrpobj.obj, but I'd like to understand why this is so difficult doing it by using 'proper'  methods.

The principal problem seems to be the ungrouping throws away the original indexing data.
Perhaps this is already not a problem ? My pandas version is **1.1.3**.

Comment: Can you share an example *as text* and show the expected output ?

Comment: @Timeless,  sorry, the original dataset is large with many rows and columns, I was hoping that someone else had a similar problem that they knew how to solve before I spent a lot of time creating an equivalent example on a smaller scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, this will help you get the original DataFrame back:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Example data
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 'value': [1, 2, 3, 4]})

# Group by 'group' column
grouped = df.groupby('group')
```

```py
# Get the original DataFrame back
df = pd.concat([group for _, group in grouped])
```

Comment: Although I had hoped to get a 'chained' solution, this at least works, as is shown with
`all(df.sort_index() == grouped.obj)
Out[147]: True` in the example above.

Comment: @JohnT What do you mean by "chained solution" in this context? Also, I don't fully understand what it is that you what filter. If you clarify this, I might be able to update my answer.

Comment: What I meant was to re-group after recovering the dataframe (perhaps with a new group index). so,
''new_group = old_group.filter(only matching indices).loc[find_subset].group(newkey)''
I think, on reflection, I was looking for a solution to a one off problem that might have been solved by a better understanding of the original data structure in the first place.
Thanks for your input.  If I do find a simple example of my problem, I'll update my post.